# Two asides not going side by side but on top of each other

Tags: css, flexbox

So i'm making a website about media query but i have a problem.

There are two asides that are supposed to move side to side of each other and are 50% of the page. The problem is that they don't move side to side but on top of each other.

Looks like a problem that should just be solved by adding width:50%; to both oh the asides but i does not seem to work. I have also tried float left and right and a lot of thing but none of the things i have tried seem to work.

I should also note that the whole page is in a flexbox which probably is a part of the problem.

Here is the code for the media query, where the problem is:

```
@media (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 37.5em){

    body section, footer, header{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: row wrap;
    }

    .aside1, .aside2{
        font-family: 'Damion', cursive;
        width:50%;
    }

}
```

Here is also the markup of the html. Only the important things (i think):

```
<section>
    <aside class="aside1"><h2>Aside 1</h2><p>Lorem ipsum.</p></aside>
    <aside class="aside2"><h2>Aside 2</h2><p>Lorem ipsum.</p></aside>
    <article>
       <h1>Article</h1>
       <p><b>Lorem ipsum.</b></p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: We need to see your markup.

Comment: And "flex-wrap: row wrap;" is invalid. But probably not related to your issue.

Comment: Yes the row wrap was just a test. Should just be row i think. Or nothing

Comment: Would you mind supplying your HTML?  The `aside` tags should be working properly with that code

Comment: There, added the html. I'm sorry it took so long. I'm completely new here and was figuring out the editor tools

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: Use float**

```css
@media (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 37.5em){
  .aside1, .aside2{
    font-family: 'Damion', cursive;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
  }
  .clear { clear: both; }
}
```

```html
<section>
<aside class="aside1"><h2>Aside 1</h2><p>Lorem ipsum.</p></aside>
<aside class="aside2"><h2>Aside 2</h2><p>Lorem ipsum.</p></aside>
<article class="clear">
   <h1>Article</h1>
   <p><b>Lorem ipsum.</b></p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</article>
</section>
```

*Once resized to the specified size, the CSS will display properly*

You can use `float` in order to make the containers sit next to each other.  If you do this, you need to make sure you have a container below it with `clear: both` or you will have layout issues.

**Solution 2: Use display**

```css
@media (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 37.5em){
  .aside1, .aside2{
    font-family: 'Damion', cursive;
    width:49%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
<aside class="aside1"><h2>Aside 1</h2><p>Lorem ipsum.</p></aside>
<aside class="aside2"><h2>Aside 2</h2><p>Lorem ipsum.</p></aside>
<article>
   <h1>Article</h1>
   <p><b>Lorem ipsum.</b></p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</article>
</section>
```

**Note**
The default `display` option in most browsers is `display: block`, which means that they cannot be set side by side unless that value is changed to `inline` or `inline-block`, or through the use of `float`. [W3Schools Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_aside.asp)

Comment: Did not fix my problem, i think. I am unsure where you want me to put the `<div class="clear"></div>` into the html. I just put it right below the aside2 like you demonstrated in the html above. Not sure if that's right though

Comment: I saw the edit. Adding the clear class into article didn't seem to work either

Comment: Sorry, I've made like 10 edits on this answer.  I added a second solution as well.  Both work for me when I resize the browser to the specified size.

Comment: Yeah well thanks. But i added into the question some code that i didn't put in because i don't think it matters. It might, but i highly doubt it.

Comment: The thing is that my friends are making basically the same website. And all they had to do to make it work was to add `width:50%;` to the asides and it worked for them. It should not be a problem in the other part of the CSS code because this is all under @media

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you then.  Both of these code snippets work without additional CSS, and simply adding `width: 50%` did not work when I tested it.

Comment: Yeah well thanks though. But the @media should all be separate and not interact with the rest of the code right? So additional CSS code should not matter.

Comment: There could still be something interfering with it.  Do you have anything else assigned to `.aside1 and .aside2`?  Try commenting it out and see if that works

Answer (score -1):

Well i found the answer. There was a little line of code that wasn't supposed to be interacting with the code that had the "problem".

The problem was that there was a line:

body section {flex-direction: column;}

This line was outside of the @media and i didn't think it would interact with that code. So i just removed that and it's fixed.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help though. Can't believe how nice random people are on the internet.